# jQuery completion bot : Cannot read property 'addClass'

Tags: javascript, bots

So I'm trying to make a bot which is autocompleting some exercises in a broken website. But I keep getting the following error: " Cannot read property 'addClass' ".

```
$(".activityPanel-actions .ng-hide").addClass("ng-show"); 
$(".activityPanel-actions .ng-hide").removeClass("ng-hide");
$(".activityPanel-actions .ng-show button").trigger('click');

$("lightbox-popup").remove();

$(".activityPanel-actions .ng-show").addClass("ng-hide");
$(".activityPanel-actions .ng-show").removeClass("ng-show");
$(".activityPanel-actions button").trigger("click");
$(".assignment-navigation.ng-isolate-scope button.button.button-white.button-next").trigger("click");
```

Also a weird thing is that it works the first time but the second time it just doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: Is that website working on jquery?

Comment: The website is persumably working working with angularJS

Answer (score -1):

Cannot read property SOMETHING on undefined means that you are trying access an element of an undefined value, in this case probably your

```
 $(".activityPanel-actions .ng-hide")
```

Does not return the HTMLElement, simply the query selector can't find object. This may throw even if you have conflict with another library reserves $ character as a global variable.

Comment: especially when you use Angular (I presume u are, because of ng-hide) - Angular and jQuery should not be loaded separately, as they don't work well together.

Comment: `$(".activityPanel-actions .ng-hide")` definitely doesn't return an HTMLElement. It returns a jQuery object. Which will definitely have `addClass`.

Comment: @ArchLicher I'm using this as a script in an excisting website.
This website has a hidden button which if you click it shows you the answer. and than you have to hide it back again to confirm your answer.
How would i do this in Angular?